# Rails routes entry to match any controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to have a test controller where I can easily add actions and have the router automatically recognize them. I'm able to create a routes entry that matches *any* controller action, (EXAMPLE 1) but can't figure out how to limit it to the test controller (EXAMPLE 2).

**routes.rb:**

```
# EXAMPLE 1: Match any generic controller actions (e.g. any_controller/any_action):
get ':controller/:action

# EXAMPLE 2: Match any test controller actions (e.g. test/any_action):
get 'test/:action'
```

The #2 example results causes a routing error:

```
routing/mapper.rb:229:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :controller (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use it as below:

```
get 'test/:action', controller: :test
```

This will create the route as below:

```
 GET    /test/:action(.:format)           test#:action
```

This will match any test controller actions (e.g. test/any_action)

Answer (score 0):

You should tell rails what shall happen with this route:

```
get ':controller/:action' => "office#show"
```

Comment: that defeats the purpose- I want it to match to *any* action, not specific actions. (And `get ':controller/:action'` by itself works fine, it's the 2nd example that fails)

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, i misunderstood your question